# Resize single ImageView inside ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I need to change an ImageView based on a condition, the problem is that ImageView sizes can be change only via ImageView.getLayoutParameters().width/height, doing so will change the width of each and every item inside the ListView.

Is there a way of changing the size of a single ImageVIew? As for now I can't find a way of doing it.

Comment: You tried it with the layout parameters?

Comment: I did, mentioned it in my post

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my custom adapter. I can re-size images by setting params to imageView. Hope this will help you!

p.s The worst thing is that in this way you have to create your view each time! It's more slowly than using viewHolder.

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Activity activity;

public Adapter(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");
    list.add("Item 4");
    list.add("Item 5");
    list.add("Item 6");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return list.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter,null);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);


    textView.setText(list.get(i));
    //Condition
    if (i == 5)
    {
        setLayoutParams(imageView,40,40);
    }
    else {
        setLayoutParams(imageView,70,70);
    }

    imageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    return convertView;
}



private View setLayoutParams(View view, int width, int height)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    return  view;
}
}
```

Comment: That is not what I've asked for. I said per ListView item. This changed the whole layout.

Comment: Ok than change this 
`if(condition)
{
  return setLayout(convertView, width, height);
}else{
  return setLayout(convertView, width, height);
}`

and change this in setLayoutParams :

`AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(width,height);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write if else condition

```
if(yourcondtion)
{
setlayoutparams();
}

else
{
setoriginallayoutparams();
}
```

Comment: As I've said. Changing the layoutparams will change the params for each and every item because ListView items are being populated from a single XML file